# Python replace array string variable into its value

Tags: python, string, parsing, search, replace

How would I be able to replace the array string into actual value programmatically without hardcoding it in python.

```
test[0] = "david"
test[1] = "23"
test[2] = "thank you"


my_string = "Hi, my name is test[0] and I am test[2] years old"
```

output:
Hi, my name is **david** and I am **23** years old

Comment: Use an f-string or some other string formatting method.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = f"Hi, my name is {test[0]} and I am {test[2]} years old"
```